# Reading a File in C isn't working?

Tags: c, file

so I tried looking around and I couldn't find an answer. I'm trying to read from a file I write in a different program. Writing it works fine, but when I try and read it, there is no output at all. Here's the code.

```
struct data{
    int tp, gpm, deg;
};

int main()
{
    struct data list[21];
    int p[21];
    list[0].tp = 10;
    FILE * fout;
    fopen("data_list", "r");
    for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++){
        fscanf(fopen, "%d:\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", &p[i], &list[i].tp, &list[i].gpm, &list[i].deg);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++){
        printf("%d:\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", p[i], list[i].tp, list[i].gpm, list[i].deg);
    }
    fclose(fout);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the file I'm trying to read

```
-10:651 17  108
-9: 514 16  142
-8: 588 16  169
-7: 542 10  160
-6: 531 17  127
-5: 688 15  158
-4: 619 18  122
-3: 658 14  170
-2: 588 11  182
-1: 541 12  139
+0: 641 19  114
+1: 668 17  200
+2: 517 19  157
+3: 589 13  121
+4: 696 13  140
+5: 526 12  157
+6: 630 12  137
+7: 685 11  105
+8: 556 11  120
+9: 645 15  188
+10:624 19  185
```

Can anyone help me out? I've only been learning C for a couple months, most of it selftaught

Comment: It looks like the tabs you're expecting to read in fscanf aren't in the input file.

Comment: write out = fopen("data_list", "r"); and keep fscanf() first arguement as  out.

Comment: As @achal mentioned, `fopen` returns a pointer to the newly opened file. You then use this handle as an identifier for the other file-related functions, like fscanf and fclose.

Comment: Don't try to read whitespace in `scanf` with the `%d` format specifier. Suppose there were **two** tabs? The `%d` format specifier (but not all) automatically filters leading whitespace.

Comment: `if((fout = fopen("data_list", "r")) == NULL) { exit(1);}`

Comment: Please read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io). Then compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and **use the debugger `gdb`**. Your *fix-my-code* question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 4):

```
fscanf(fopen, "%d:\t%d\t%d\t%d\n"
```

I have no idea how that possibly even compiled, but you are passing a function pointer where a `FILE*` is required.  That definitely will not work correctly.

The correct thing to pass there is the return value from your `fopen()` call (which at the moment you've been discarding).

Comment: So I adjusted this line, (after actually looking at it I can't believe it compiled either), with this one 

    fscanf(fout, "%d%d%d%d", &p[i], &list[i].tp, &list[i].gpm, &list[i].deg);

but it's still giving me nothing. I also actually utilized fout and defined it with 

fout = fopen("data_list", "r");

and It's still not working.